# How to mock answers of the Google App Engine services (e.g. blobstore)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit

I'm trying to create a unit test for my Google App Engine project. The use case is as follows: a client queries the API for an upload URL, as the data needs to be stored in the blobstore, the client recieves a JSON encoded structure with the URL. The client then uploads the data to that URL.

The implementation of the servlet is fairly simple:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    result.put("uploadurl", BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService()
            .createUploadUrl("/api/v1/import"));
    gson.toJson(result, resp.getWriter());
}
```

In good fashion there should be a test to see whether the client does indeed receive the right data. So there should be a counter JUnit test. I was hoping to mock the blob store service so that it would return a fixed upload url, which the test then can check.

However, I have no idea how to overrule the blobstore service. Using Mockito I can't mock the static getBlobstoreService(), using the LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig I have no idea how I can overrule the answer to createUploadUrl().

My attempt to write a test was something like this:

```
public class ImportServletTest {
   public static class Response {
    String uploadurl;

    void setUploadurl(String url) {
        this.uploadurl = url;
    }
}

private LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig blobstoreConfig = new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig();

private LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(blobstoreConfig);
@Test
public void getsUploadURL() throws IOException, ServletException {
    ImportServlet servlet = new ImportServlet();

    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    try (CharArrayWriter output = new CharArrayWriter();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);) {
        when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

        servlet.doGet(null, response);
        writer.flush();

        Response apiResponse = new Gson().fromJson(output.toString(), Response.class);
        assertEquals("http://mysite/_ah/theurl", apiResponse.uploadurl);
    }
}

@Before
public void setupGae() throws IOException {
    helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void teardownGae() {
    helper.tearDown();
}
}
```

Comment: Can't you pass that blob store service as a parameter to your servlet's constructor?

Comment: Servlets will be instantiated by the servlet framework and require a no-arg constructor. I could of course supply multiple constructors, passing the real gae services into a different constructor, but this makes the code more difficult than it needs to be. Also, I'm not sure if it is allowed to access the services in the servlet's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking static classes/methods is in general very dangerous (http://googletesting.blogspot.it/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html), but in a similar case I had some success using PowerMock (https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to override the behavior of static classes that were not under my control. I guess you'll have to mock the entire method chain:

```
BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().createUploadUrl()
```

to return a custom URL instead of that generated by the BlobStore.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. Shame that in order to test such a simple method my test code explodes in size and complexity.